# Trying to Connect to different database

Tags: wpdb

I want to get list of 5 recent posts from a subdomain (not multisite) to show on our main domain. Following is the code am trying to execute, but is giving the error - Invalid arguments supplied in foreach()

```
global $wpdb;
$second_db = new wpdb('user','pass','db','localhost');
$rows = $second_db->get_results('SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type="post" and post_status="publish" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5');

echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($rows as $obj) :
    echo "<li>".$obj->post_title."</li>";
  endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

I even tried to supply OBJECT, ARRAY_N etc within get_results and also tried to use `$wpdb->prepare` but nothing worked. Any ideas?

PS. The other database is also on the same server.

EDIT:

via `$wpdb->print_error();` it shows -

```
WordPress database error: [] SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE
option_name = '_transient_feed_mod_eec437511a934edf3e159e1cc8a5844b'
LIMIT 1
```

via `$second_db->print_error();` it shows -

```
Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

**EDIT 2:**

Finally the following code is working, I've realized the mistake and have mentioned it in comment. Now, when everything is running fine, I am receiving following text (error, if you may) before the output.

```
WordPress database error: []
```

Code -

```
global $wpdb;
        $second_db = new wpdb('user','pass','db','localhost');
        $second_db->show_errors();
        $second_db->print_error();
        $rows = $second_db->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type="post" and post_status="publish" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5');
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($rows as $obj) :
            echo "<li>";
                echo '<a href="' . $obj->guid . '">' . $obj->post_title . '</a>';
            echo "</li>";
        endforeach;
        echo "</ul>";
```

Also, is there a better way to get permalink of the post instead of using `$obj->guid`?

Comment: Have you reviewed for any errors?  Please take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors for details on how you can enable the display of SQL errors in wpdb; and, when you have done so, would you mind sharing the information you receive?

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you using `$wpdb->print_error()` or `$second_db->print_error()` to get the error? You should use the latter, since that's the one you're trying to get data from.

Comment: I again updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you running the `print_error()` method right after you execute the query? It's hard to get a full picture from your code snippets. Also: Why aren't you using the build in methods from `$wpdb` to access the data, but adding a raw query with static table names?

Comment: Are you sure your connection credentials are correct? The ones you use to create the new object?

Comment: Thank You guys. The problem was indeed with the databse connection setting. I was stupidly trying on the localhost instead of the live site. Pardon me for the silly mistake.

Also @kaiser , I am using this approach because I do not know/see any other method to access database of sub-domain and fetch latest posts to show onto main domain's front page. I though successfully tried to fetch feed, but I want to access database because we want to reflect any change (or addition) in sub-domain's post immediately on to our main domain's front page.

Comment: I've edited the question (Edit 2). Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at [wp-db.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L0) and see:

```
1384                            if ( $this->dbh->connect_errno ) {
1385                                    $this->dbh = null;
```

This is in the class function `db_connect()`, which is called by the `wpdb` constructor.  In the latest error you describe:

> Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

we can see that `mysql_error()` is not receiving the appropriate argument.  This argument comes into play here:

```
1211            public function print_error( $str = '' ) {
1212                    global $EZSQL_ERROR;
1213    
1214                    if ( !$str ) {
1215                            if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
1216                                    $str = mysqli_error( $this->dbh );
1217                            } else {
1218                                    $str = mysql_error( $this->dbh );
1219                            }
1220                    }
```

Note lines 1216 and 1218 (it differs based on whether you use mysqli extension).  The argument it is passing in is your MySQL connection resource, which as seen on 1384-1385 is not defined correctly if there is a MySQL connection issue.  This will make it difficult to trace the error at the point you're doing so from, but at least now you know it's an issue with the connection.

As @s_ha_dum indicated, you should verify your connection information to ensure that you're able to connect.  If you have `WP_DEBUG` set to `false`, the `mysql_connect()` (lines 1409, 1411) and `mysqli_real_connect()` (lines 1379, 1381) are run with the `@` prefix that suppresses errors.  Enable `WP_DEBUG` and you should receive error text for these lines, if that is indeed where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks @justin. I enabled WP-Debug and that pointed out the mistake. The problem was indeed with the connection settings. Thanks for the awesome explanation. I though, have updated  the question (EDIT 2) can you please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

The only neat way to get a full permalink is to make use of the get_permalink() function, @see
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

```
get_permalink($obj->ID);
```

Comment: No, I tried this. This assumes that the $obj->ID resides in the current database (which in this case is main domain db) instead of going to subdomain's db and using get_permalink function there.

Comment: @vajrasar The GUID is a unique ID string, nothing else. It's no reliable source from where you can fetch permalinks. For e.g.: If you export/import data, the GUID does not change and will point to completely unrelated posts. What Ramon showed you is the _only_ way to go, no matter how you retrieve the ID.

Comment: Allright .. I see your problem as the current (main) WPCore WPDB database data source != the database data source you are using.

Comment: Is there no AJAX/bootstrap method you can use on your secondary source to do queries, get_permalink() and return you data using JSON/XML ?

Next to AJAX, you might like this one:

 
[wordpress][snipplet][plugin] Standalone cron.php to call WordPress functions
Permalink: http://www.ramonfincken.com/permalink/topic187.html